# What is the SharePoint 2013 Release date?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

What is the SharePoint Server 2013 Release date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SharePoint 2013 RTM (Release to Manufacturing) release date was October 11, 2012.

[Office Reaches RTM!](http://blogs.office.com/b/office-news/archive/2012/10/11/office-reaches-rtm.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I have found nothing about SharePoint Server 2013 RTM.

Comment: could you help me to understand, what are the dates of Preview Version and RTM? If release is already available, where can I buy it? I see only a trial version for 180 days.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview-collaboration-software-FX103789438.aspx Gives you an option to buy SharePoint Online or On-premises server CALs for licensing.